# Android services, possible or not?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm working on an app in which I want to run some services when default Android options are accessed, i.e. when Play Music or Gallery is accessed generate a `Toast` and so on...  Is it possible to do this?? Here is my code.

Here is where I start my service in the Main `Activity`:

```
if(autoBrightOn){
  startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}
```

and my `Service.class`

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.w(" ibinder ","");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
//        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Created",0).show();
        Log.w(TAG, "onCreate");

            }

   @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
//        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Stopped",0).show();
//        Log.w(TAG, "onDestroy");
//        player.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "My Service Started :"+intent+" start id :"+startid,0).show();
//        Log.d(TAG, "onStart");
//        player.start();

        Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      intentBrowseFiles.setType("image/*");
      intentBrowseFiles.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      startActivity(intentBrowseFiles);                   

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a custom `BroadcastReceiver` and listen for different `Intent`s sent out.  There doesn't appear to be a 'catch-all' `ACTIVITY_STARTED` so you may need to create a pretty detailed list of `Intent`s to listen for.  Here's the Android `Intent` Reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Hmmmm, maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Yeah, sounds good. Any sort of code snippet would be more fruitful.

Comment: Well I'm busy with my job and other projects, I can't do it for you.  I would look at how to create custom `BroadcastReceivers` by reading this:  http://androidword.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-use-broadcast-receiver.html  You'll have to scour the `Intent` reference I posted for you above to contextualize your actions

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Make a class that extends Service and override the onCreate(), onDestroy(), and onBind() methods. In your main manifest, put

```
<service android:name=".GameServerService"/>
```

, but replace .GameServerService with the name of your service. Then in your main class, put:

```
Intent gameServerService = new Intent(this, GameServerService.class);
```

Use

```
this.startService(gameServerService);
```

and

```
this.stopService(gameServerService);
```

as needed. Good luck!

Comment: I copied that code to try it out and it runs ok when I comment out the  intentBrowseFiles.setType("image/*"); line. I'd look there for why it's crashing.

Comment: What is the behaviour of that code when you try to run it?? And did you run on the device or emulator??

Comment: It also works when I take out Intent.ACTION_VIEW from the parenthesis and just put Intent intentBrowseFiles = new Intent(); and leave in the other line. It seems to bring up an action view anyway. I am testing on an emulator. It says "Complete action using" and lists "Contact icon", "Crop picture", "Gallery", etc... It does the same on my tablet running Android 2.2

Comment: Yeah, they are showing..can a toast be generated when i select any of the option.??

Comment: That's where @JustLikeThat 's answer comes in. I haven't done that before, but it sounds like a good way of doing it. Try out his links first and there should be other examples if you do a quick search.